# How to properly draw bytes to a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, rendering

So, I have done this before and for some reason, this code no longer works I have tried doing it as a BufferStrategy and a JPanel but neither one works.

Here is my code:

```
    File ClimateFile = new File(ClimateDir);
            Render render = new Render();
            byte[] ClimateByte = render.getFileImage(ClimateFile, ".png");

            g.drawBytes(ClimateByte, 0, ClimateByte.length, 0, 0);
```

The file does exist.
When I print out the stream data the data is correct with the hex code.
if I do g.drawtext it works but any other method does not seem to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone is wondering how to do this it is nearly impossible to do it correctly.

Instead, I converted the RenderEngine to use Int arrays and converted the Int Array to a BufferedImage then I did Graphics.DrawImage.